# Clunky Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I made a carousel using bootstrap but when the images change they're all clunky and the background shows white while they change, it's really not pleasing to the eyes at all.
It's the fist time I use bootstrap's carousel, so maybe I did something wrong... Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row mainSlider">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="main_slider" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#main_slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#main_slider" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#main_slider" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/slide.jpg">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Title of the Slide</h3>
                        <p>Content of the Slide</p>
                        <a href="/services" class="viewMore">View More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/slide.jpg">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Title of the Slide 2</h3>
                        <p>Content of the Slide 3</p>
                        <a href="/services" class="viewMore">View More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/slide.jpg">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Title of the Slide 3</h3>
                        <p>Content of the Slide 3</p>
                        <a href="/services" class="viewMore">View More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And some custom CSS I did to make it fit my design:

```
.mainSlider {
    height:443px;
}
#main_slider {
    height:100%;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner{
    height:100%;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item img {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item h3 {
    margin:90px 0 30px 0;
    font-size:45px;
    font-family:Merriweather;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item p {
    font-size:17px;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item a.viewMore {
    margin:20px 0;
    padding:10px 25px;
    background-color:#eb7022;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:4px;
}
```

Here's [a gif](https://gyazo.com/e2676617e3a18cb31d38b4aece199641) of how it looks right now.
Sorry if this is something really dumb, I'm very new to frontend development.
Thanks!

**EDIT** Here's a screencast in case you can't see the gif: http://screencast.com/t/hWtUZcpRD

Comment: The gif link is not working.

Comment: @Topr Hmm, weird.. Anyway, here's a screencast: http://screencast.com/t/hWtUZcpRD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things that need to be changed:

1) Remove `position:relative;` from `.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item`, this will stop the delay between slides so there isn't any white space.

2) You should only have the `.active` class applied to your first slide. not all of them.

Also:

This may not apply as you may have additional CSS etc all ready handling this but I changed the way you inner text and button are applies so they remain inside the slides when the viewport changes. It's just reverting back to the built in `carousel-caption` class and adjusting the content as needed.

See working example

```css
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item {
  color: #fff;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item h3 {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: Merriweather;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item p {
  font-size: 17px;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item a.viewMore {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-color: #eb7022;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.mainSlider #main_slider .carousel-inner .item .carousel-caption {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mainSlider">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="main_slider" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#main_slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#main_slider" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#main_slider" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/2350x1000/000">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Title of the Slide</h3>

            <p>Content of the Slide</p> <a href="/services" class="viewMore">View More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/2350x1000/f00">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Title of the Slide</h3>

            <p>Content of the Slide</p> <a href="/services" class="viewMore">View More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/2350x1000/ff0">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Title of the Slide</h3>

            <p>Content of the Slide</p> <a href="/services" class="viewMore">View More <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```